# Poisson's equation to a grounded plane of charge

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

How does Poisson's equation apply to a grounded plane of charge, where the laplacian of the potential gives $-ρ/ε₀$, even though it is grounded, implying it should have a voltage of 0 and thus laplacian is also 0? And since theres charge ρ should not be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Poisson’s equation holds here as it does in all electrostatics. Take the charged plate to lie in the $z=0$ plane with charge density $\sigma$. Then Poisson’s equation reads

$$\nabla^2 \varphi = -\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon}=-\frac{\sigma\delta(z)}{\varepsilon}$$

with boundary condition $\varphi(z=0)=0$, and another relating derivatives of the scalar potential to the surface charge.

Just because the scalar potential is zero at a point, doesn’t mean it’s Laplacian is zero. A function can equal zero for a particular input, but have nonzero derivative.